# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' Getting Error unknowingly on CMD. How to resolve it?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
[21/Mar/2018 16:28:54] "GET /static/chapters/svg/h8-b-01.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
[21/Mar/2018 16:29:10] "GET /static/chapters/images/newh-down-indicator-b.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1028
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:47] "POST /myaccount/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 23860
Not Found: /svg/reasoning_skill_shadow.svg
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:48] "GET /static/chapters/svg/h8-b-01.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:48] "GET /svg/reasoning_skill_shadow.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 3890
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:48] "GET /static/chapters/js/newh.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8000
Not Found: /svg/question_ans.svg
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:48] "GET /svg/question_ans.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 3860
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[21/Mar/2018 16:32:48] "GET /static/chapters/js/newh.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59852)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Arun Pandey\AppData\Local\Programs\python\python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------

C:\Users\Arun Pandey\Desktop\src>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 21, 2018 - 16:38:19
Django version 1.11.6, using settings 'maths.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I am getting this error only on cmd. I have no idea from where it is coming. Please help to remove this.

```
    """
    Django settings for maths project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.11.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'i$*nj0(qn4&b402jjag@ql3#*z@^9(axmay=7s+b6t(h8cpym9'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'students',
        'commons',
        'community',
        'chapters',
        'assignment',
        'search',
        'courses',
        'cart',
        'orders',
        'billing',
        'addresses',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'maths.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',

                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'maths.wsgi.application'
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'students.User'

    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'maths',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'ishwar',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/


    STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
    ]

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")

    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'students:login'
    LOGIN_URL = 'chapters:list'
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'students:unlogged'
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```